# Do we have a policy on swearing / cussing?

Tags: discussion, policy

I've just had one user flag 4 posts for the use of the work "fuck" in them.

What should be the policy here?

Honestly I don't find the word offensive in the way it is being used in these questions, e.g.

> is (something that happened) a big 'fuck-you' to (someone)?

However I would find it unacceptable for a user here to use such language to another user, or to post something that is deliberately offensive to other users.

I don't think its my job as moderator, or other high-reputation users to respond to flags because someone finds the language disagreeable, where my only choice is to delete the post or edit the post myself. If such a user can edit the post themselves, and still keep the meaning intact, then they can perform the edit.

Comment: I also want to make it clear that I'm very happy for the user to have brought this to my attention - I just want a discussion on the policy.

Comment: I would have edited those posts myself. But I was not sure what the policy on instances such as the one you have quoted was. Assuming that there's no MTV policy on this, what's the SO policy on the use of such language?

Comment: @coleopterist - understood - and I thought that was why you'd done that.  Thanks for prompting the discussion.

Comment: While there are instances where it is necessary (like quotes and such, or purposely immitating the style of another speaker, even if not exactly quoting) and while I am not really offended, the use from your example really doesn't seem necessary and a more formal language could also have been employed. But I'm not really offended by it either (and I realize that American English uses this word much more freely and generically than other languages, where you wouldn't really want to read that in a general message, even in a colloquial one).

Comment: It depends on case by case. Many time i edit question where fuck,bullshit are written unnecessarily but if it's a movie quote, then i don't mind them. And sometime they doesn't offend either.

Comment: Related [Is there any problem using 18+ words on M&Tv](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/862/is-there-any-problem-using-18-words-on-mtv)